# How to search users folders while avoiding digging too deep using DIR?

Tags: batch-file, search, cmd, scripting, directory

How to search all users' folders and list the files found (with extensions) in an output text file using .bat (cmd) without including data from `AppData` folders?

Let's say I have user `Jenny` and user `Tommy`. And of course within those users there are folders such as `desktop`, `documents`, `videos`, etc.

How can I create a CMD (or PowerShell) script that will search through each users' folders like `desktop`, `documents`, `videos`, etc., **BUT** prevent the script from pulling results found in the `AppData` folder.

I was trying to use this code to search each user, but the results were being watered down by what was found in each users `AppData` folders.

I used `%~dp0Files.txt` to have the results exported to the desktop where I was executing the .bat from.

```
cd..
cd..
cd Users
dir /s /p /b >> %~dp0Files.txt
pause
```

I appreciate any advice. Even if there is a different script file that is better to use for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the command line:

```
dir "%USERPROFILE%\..\*" /A-D /B /S | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /C:"\\AppData\\" >"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Files.txt"
```

The command **DIR** searches

- from parent directory of the current user's profile directory being usually `C:\Users` on Windows Vista and later Windows versions
- for just files because of `/A-D` (not attribute directory)
- recursive in this directory and all subdirectories because of `/S` and
- list them in bare format because of `/B` which means just the file names with full path.

This output is redirected to **FINDSTR** which searches in the lines

- case-insensitive because of `/I` and
- literally because of `/L`
- for the string `\AppData\`
- and outputs all lines NOT containing this string because of `/V` (inVerted result).

The backslash character is the escape character in search strings.
Therefore each backslash to find literally must be escaped with one more backslash.

It is possible to specify multiple search strings which are OR combined by using multiple `/C:"..."` arguments on **FINDSTR** command line. So it is easily possible to filter out more subdirectories.

The filtered output of **FINDSTR** is redirected into file `Files.txt` on desktop of current user always created new on each execution of this command line.

For understanding the two used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely the help displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `findstr /?`

And read the Wikipedia articles about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

Comment: Wow, that was thorough and very well explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Mofi's** help I was able to also add an exclusion for the All Users folder which was also watering down the results.

My final coded ended up being:

```dos
:ScanUsers
@echo off
cls
ECHO Searching users' files
dir "%USERPROFILE%\..\*" /A-D /B /S | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /C:"\\AppData\\" >"%~dp0Output\FilesSearch.txt"
start "%~dp0Output\FilesSearch.txt"
wscript.exe "%~dp0Extra\Here is a list of files.vbs"
Timeout 2
goto start
```

%~dp0Output just directs the text document to be saved into a specific file on the desktop